# Trouble installing 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cant' install 'matplotlib.pyplot' on Windows 10, Python 3.7

I tried 'pip install matplotlib.pyplot' and received an error

Here's the exact error code:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pyplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: `pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `pip install matplotlib.pyplot`, use `pip install matplotlib`

`matplotlib.pyplot` is calling `pyplot` from the module `matplotlib`. What you want is the module, `matplotlib`. Then from idle or wherever you are running this, you can call `matplotlib.pyplot`

Answer (score 0):

Try just using pip install on your command line (or terminal):

'pip install matplotlib'

I hope it helps.
BR